# FFmpeg HLS Live Stream Stuck with iOS 11

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I've exp with FFmpeg but i recent problem with iOS 11 (Recent release for Apple)

I used FFmpeg for stream HLS Live Stream for only iPhone and iPad in closed app for online courses. My problem is the next:

I used this code for HLS Live Stream:

```
ffmpeg -i "Input" -preset fast -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -crf 18 -profile:v baseline -maxrate 1000k -bufsize 1835k -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:a 64k -flags -global_header -hls_time 20 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 /m3u8/test.m3u8
```

This work perfect in iOS 8, 9 and 10 devices. But with new version iOS 11, video is stuck after about 30 to 40 seconds, as seen in the image:

[ios11stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdqjE.png)

I have searched for hours and hours. I have done many tests, but I can not get it out, since it works perfectly with iOS 8,9 and 10 (test in somes devices, even working perfectly on a device with iOS 10, update to iOS 11, and stop working immediately, downgrade to iOS 10 and work again)

I hope someone can help me out, thank you and greetings to all

Comment: Do you have a public URL of that stream to test?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, it's ready to work only from the app.